# How to get 24h Visa free transit permit at Shanghai Pudong international airport

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, pvg

I am an Indian citizen and I have a layover of 21 h at PVG before heading towards Montreal ,Canada on the next day. I have hotel booking at PVG airport for my layover period.

I want to know step by step procedure to get 24h Visa free transit permit immediately after landing at Shanghai PVG airport.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 24h visa by following the steps by

1. Fill an Arrival/Departure Card at the border inspection counter
2. Get the temporary entry permit stamp or sticker
3. Claim the luggage (if needed)
4. Go through the customs

More details : https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm

Comment: Please don't just link to external answers, but summarize the content here.