# How to get temporary pass at Shanghai PVG airport for 9-hour layover?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, pvg

I am going from India to the USA for tourism purpose. I am an Indian citizen. I will have a 9-hour layover at Shanghai Airport PVG. Upon landing at PVG, I wanted to exit the airport for 2-3 hours of sightseeing and then get back to the airport. Layovers less than 24 hours have visa-free transit.

As told [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/140143/100100), I have to get the temporary entry permit stamp or sticker on my passport. Can someone tell the exact gate number etc. where one has to go for doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

At Shanghai Pu Dong airport the desk for all visa related applications are located just before passport control you really cannot miss it as you come downstairs to go through the health checkpoint before passport control